# Adding contextual properties to Serilog logging of exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, serilog

I want to dynamically add a context value to my error logging in ASP.NET MVC. However I only have this property after a login with success.

Currently I have this setup at my startup.cs:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
//other Enrich settings
.Enrich.WithProperty("AccountID", AccountID)
.CreateLogger();
```

I have tried to in my solution after a exception to logging:

```
Log.Information("Adding {AccountID}", AccountID);
```

And:

```
using (LogContext.PushProperty("AccountID", AccountID))
{
    Log.Information("Adding {AccountID}", AccountID);
}
```

But nothing solve actually the problem.
Someone have more options/ways to resolve this issue?

Comment: `.Enrich.WithProperty("AccountID", AccountID)` -> [`Enrich.FromLogContext()`](https://nblumhardt.com/2016/08/context-and-correlation-structured-logging-concepts-in-net-5/)

Comment: @RubenBartelink you say to change in startup configuration the 

    .Enrich.WithProperty("AccountID", AccountID)

for

    Enrich.FromLogContext()

And in the catch´s exception how i can insert/update the value in enrich?

Comment: It would have been a good idea to mention the fact that you're in an exception handler and/or what you expect ;) I was pointing out that 1) reassigning the logger wont work and is a bad idea 2) for PushProperty you want the Enrich.FromLogContext. The value is captured into the `LogEvent` on the executing thread at the time you call `.Information`, along with anything that has been added via `PushProperty` up the stack.

Comment: The problem is, while LogContext holds values, they get popped off by the `using` as an exception unravels the stack; the mechanism is not intended to cover this case. I'd suggest re-asking more clearly 1. saying "I log like this:" (explain how/where you do it) 2. I'd like to include some context (e.g. an AccountId) (I have ideas but am not sure how best to flow values like this in aspnet; not just trying to dodge the question - the point is (assuming you are trying to hook it into top level logging) that a full answer involves more aspnet stuff than Serilog concerns))

Comment: @RubenBartelink but i mentioned previsiously in the question: "I have tried to in my solution after a exception to logging", but yes i understand maybe i had explained not so right...

After the catch exception i want to add AccountID property with value to a new collumn serilog and insert it on a table, thats the main goal, but at startup i cant know the accountID, i expect catch it in every Exceptions, during the flow...

Comment: Yes, that's clear now that we've had the discussion. Unfortunately I don't know the best idiomatic approach for asp.net. I've tried to reword your post a bit to encompass some of these things. I personally don't know the answer so hopefully someone will be along in due course.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serilog Logcontext properties are gone after exception handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55223744/serilog-logcontext-properties-are-gone-after-exception-handler)